# Retorno de um create function errado

Tags: sql, postgresql

Eu possuo a seguinte tabela no schema utfpr:

```
create table Matricula(
    dis_sigla varchar(50), 
    tur_numero varchar(15),
    alu_ra varchar(100) ,
    mat_ano date,
    mat_nota float not null,
    constraint pk_matricula primary key (dis_sigla,tur_numero,alu_ra,mat_ano),
    constraint fk_mat_dis_sigla_tur_numero foreign key (dis_sigla, tur_numero) references Turma(dis_sigla,tur_numero) on delete cascade,
    constraint fk_mat_alu_nome foreign key (alu_ra) references Aluno(alu_ra) on delete cascade
);
```

Eu preciso cria uma function que receba como parametro a coluna de RA (alu_ra) e ela me devolva os RAs seguidos da sigla da disciplina (dis_sigla), portanto fiz essa function:

```
create function raSigla(ra utfpr.matricula.alu_ra%type) returns text as $$
declare
    string utfpr.matricula.dis_sigla%type;
begin
    select * into string from utfpr.matricula where matricula.alu_ra = ra; 
    return ra || ' -- ' || string;   
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

select raSigla(alu_ra) from utfpr.matricula;
```

Porém, estou recebendo os RAs com a sigla repetida, como a seguir, fato que não deveria acontecer

```
1   1997530 -- EC35A
2   1997530 -- EC35A
3   1997530 -- EC35A
4   1997530 -- EC35A
5   1997530 -- EC35A
6   1997530 -- EC35A
7   1997530 -- EC35A
8   1997530 -- EC35A
```

Como que posso resolver isso?

Comment: **1.** por que não usa um `distinct`? **2.** pelo que entendi no relacionamento você pode pegar essa informação da tabela `Aluno`, pode fazer a consulta nela (onde a matrícula é chave - tendo só um retorno)

Comment: Já tentou utilizar um return query ou return next e não um return escalar? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING